Side panel font size
I would like to increase the font side of the text in the side panel, especially when it is in Structure mode. I can change font size for the editor window using the Configuration tools but have not found a way to change font size in the side panel. How do you change the font size in the side panel?
Using TeXstudio 4.8.1

You must be referring to some (TeX) editor, but which one? Please edit your question to clarify.

TeXstudio 4.8.1

I was able to change font size in side panel by changing parameter settings in the General menu (Style, Color Scheme, Icon Theme, Font, Font Size) in Configure TeXstudio. My changes took effect after closing the application and reopening.
